# Fixing contour lines in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, contour

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop and I want the lines to be curvy not that straight as the picture depicts:

[image]

solution: In Arcgis , the smooth lines tool , peak ...

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: You have to use software raster to vector like R2V or wintopo

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @nagib the data pictured looks like it has already been raster to vector converted.

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: I'll re-open the question so that you can move the answer from within your question to be an answer of at least a few sentences.  It is fine and encouraged to self-answer when you can.

Comment: It looks like your DEM is an integer raster.. the contour tool is dutifully doing what it's supposed to but it's not pleasing to the eye. I would (and have) recommend smoothing the raster not the lines. How you do this depends on your software choices; as it's free I suggest gdal_translate to double the cell size (-outsize 200% 0) with -ot Float32 -r cubicspline and then back to the same cell size (or slightly smaller) with the same resample method before generating the contours.

Comment: thank you man , I know little about programmation , so I can't use what you suggest.

Comment: The canonical solution is to use a low pass filter, as described in the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-filter-works.htm) to "fuzz" the integer values, which prevents the contour generation code from generating zig-zag patterns.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> The canonical solution is to use a low pass filter, as described in
>   the
>   [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-filter-works.htm)
>   to "fuzz" the integer values, which prevents the contour generation
>   code from generating zig-zag patterns.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Miles-Stimson comment the following :

> It looks like your DEM is an integer raster.. the contour tool is
>   dutifully doing what it's supposed to but it's not pleasing to the
>   eye. I would (and have) recommend smoothing the raster not the lines.

In my opinion, integer or not, it doesn't really matter but the idea is the right one.

What Michael ideas refers at is that the stairs-type pattern is caused by the **resolution of your raster**. To solve this with Arcgis tools (with Spatial analysis extension), you can use the [**Resample Tool in ArcToolbox**](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm). You need to use the "**bilinear**" technique of resampling to achieve the best rendering.

For example, if your raster resolution is one meter and you set it to 0.01m, you'll see your contours will look much less blocky, because the blocky steps will not be any more of 1 meter side but 10cm.

**Alternative solution** should you not have Spatial Analyst is to use [**gdal_translate**](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) (you can find it as a command line tool when you install QGIS) with the following options :

> double the cell size (-outsize 200% 0) with `-ot Float32 -r cubicspline` and then back to the same cell size (or slightly smaller) with the same resample method before generating the contours.

One can also resample with bilinear option with [**gdalwarp**](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) :

`gdalwarp  -t_srs EPSG:[your EPSG code] ...codes... **-r bilinear** input.tif output.tif`